# Add SQL triggers

Tags: sql

I have created wine management database and I have 3 tales WineStock, Orders and OrderLine they are connected together in that way Orders with OrderLine and WineStock with OrderLine. What I want to do is to create a trigger that comppares DateNow and DeliveryDate and if it is already delivered then have a function that takes WineQuantity and minus orderQuantity and refresh the WineQuantity.
What is the best way to do that? Should I create a trigger that inside I join the tables and then compare date function and add calculation function. Or there is a better way to achieve the result I want?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps knowing the database will help us. After a couple of bottles I have _3 tales WineStock_

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I don't think you want to implement a trigger to change the orderline table. What you are asking for will ultimately show you never had any items ordered once they are all delivered. If you have to go back and determine how much wine was ordered, where would you get the information from? What I would do is either have a  delivery table that would track deliveries and tie back to the order table or create a many to many relationship between orders and the new delivery table so that a delivery could potential deliver multiple orders. You would need to provide more information on how a deliver is tracked currently.